# I receive an empty message, sending from python and smtplib

Tags: python, email, send

I want send a email fom python, i read my file (myfile) but i receive one email empty... which it is my mistake ? Thanks very much community !

My code:

```
f1 = open('myfile') 
print(f1.read())

fromaddr = 'chucknorris@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'brucelee@icloud.com'
msg = "\r\n".join([
"From:" + fromaddr,
"To:" + toaddrs,
"Subject: Message from SB",
"",
str(f1.read())
])
username = 'chucknorris@gmail.com'
password = 'ChuckImmortal'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the whole file here:

```
f1 = open('myfile') 
print(f1.read())
```

Now the file pointer is at the end; any further calls to `f1.read()` will return an empty string unless some other process were to add more data to the file. Either read the whole message into memory, and then print, or remove that `print()` call, or use `f1.seek(0)` to move the pointer back to the start.

Reading the file into a variable would solve this, for example:

```
with open('myfile') as f1:
    contents = f1.read()
print(contents)

msg = "\r\n".join([
    "From:" + fromaddr,
    "To:" + toaddrs,
    "Subject: Message from SB",
    "",
    contents
])
```